# Inequality proof with sequences - showing $x_n<x_{n+1}$ for $x_{n+1}=x_n^2 + 1/4$, $x<1/2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, inequality, induction, recurrence-relations

[image: the question]

So I was doing part 2 of this question and I wanted to know if my approach is correct.

$x_{n+1} - x_n = x_n^2 + 1/4 - x_n$

Now since it is a sequence of positive terms 
$x_n$ > 0

Therefore $x_n^2 + 1/4 > 1/4 > x_n$

Hence  $x_n^2 + 1/4 - x_n > 0$

$x_{n+1} - x_n > 0$

$x_n < x_{n+1}$

Comment: I think your reasoning is not so good. See my post.

Comment: The same idea from [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2880997/291201) to your other question works here as well: $\;x_{n+1}-x_n=x_n^2-x_{n-1}^2\,$.

Comment: In case it helps, here is another question about the same recurrence: [$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4}+a_n^2$ is converging and have a limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/246688). Drawing [cobweb plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_plot) might help to get some intuition in problems like this, you can see some examples [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14150/conversation/pictures-illustrating-iterations-for-x-n1fx-n) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1884302). In this case, the function is $f(x)=x^2+\frac14$.

Answer (score 1):

(i).

Because by assumption of the induction  $$x_{n+1}=x_n^2+\frac{1}{4}<\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

$(ii).$

$$x_{n+1}-x_n=x_n^2-x_n+\frac{1}{4}=\left(x_n-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2>0.$$